# some IE9 turn into Compatibility View on Ajax request

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9, prototypejs

I have a web application that uses ajax with prototype.js (`Ajax.Updater`).

```
new Ajax.Updater('someID','/some/url',
    {
        asynchronous:true,
        evalScripts:true,
        parameters:Form.serialize(Event.element(event).form),
        requestHeaders:['X-Update', 'someID']
    }
);
```

Some (not all) IE9 users experience a strange phenomenon.

- `UserAgent` of normal (non-ajax) HTTP requests indicates that the browser is IE9, not in Compatibility View.
- `UserAgent` of ajax HTTP requests indicates that the browser is IE7 (IE9's Compatibility View).

I want to force the browser not to use Compatibility View in ajax HTTP requests, but the html already has a `meta` tag : `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`.

Does anyone know the reason or workaround?

Comment: Similar question: [IE8 forces compatibility mode when inserting data into a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614286/ie8-forces-compatibility-mode-when-inserting-data-into-a-div). Maybe some markup/styling in received HTML fragment forces IE9 to go into compatibility mode?

Comment: Thanks, @Victor. I will investigate HTMLs, but it may take long time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution - but not fully researched - try setting

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
```

in your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` file - this will add the X-UA-Compatible header to all responses from Apache to force IE not to use Compatibility Mode

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and observe for a while.

Comment: I have never seen the issue since I installed this. It MAY be the solution, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Concur. Same issue here - above seems to be the solution.