# jQuery autocomplete - IE8 issue - this tab has been recovered

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I run into a problem with jQuery UI - Autocomplete and IE8.

I'm using `combobox` method which you can find on jQuery UI website - **[here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)**

Basically, it is creating autocomplete input + select menu from `select/option` list.

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.16; both from google server.

It is working perfectly on Chrome / FF / Opera, but does not work on IE8.

On IE8 - once you select something (after typing), or use dropdown button IE will reload the page. **Please not that IE will not crash till you use arrows or try to select something.**

- `res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#,` in the URL, in front of the actual path
- or a message `this tab has been reloaded; a problem with the page causes IE to close and reopen the page`

**[Live example here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/AutoCompleteIE/index.html)**

**Any idea what is causing IE to act like that? Any suggestion much appreciated.**

---

jQuery code:

```
    <script>
    (function( $ ) {
        $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
            _create: function() {
                var self = this,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                var input = this.input = $( "<input>" )
                    .insertAfter( select )
                    .val( value )
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function( request, response ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                            response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                                var text = $( this ).text();
                                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }) );
                        },
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function( event, ui ) {
                            if ( !ui.item ) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                    if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if ( !valid ) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $( this ).val( "" );
                                    select.val( "" );
                                    input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

                input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li></li>" )
                        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                        .appendTo( ul );
                };

                this.button = $( "<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>" )
                    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                    .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                    .insertAfter( input )
                    .button({
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                    .click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                            input.autocomplete( "close" );
                            return;
                        }

                        // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                        $( this ).blur();

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                        input.focus();
                    });
            },

            destroy: function() {
                this.input.remove();
                this.button.remove();
                this.element.show();
                $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );

    $(document).ready( function() {

        $("#combobox").combobox();

    });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still trying to work out *why* IE8 is crashing but it **does** work for me when you add a jQueryUI theme to the page, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
```

**Edit:** I think I know which line it is crashing on, but I still do not know why! In the [jQueryUI code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js) `activate: function( event, item ) {`

is the following code which adds style and an attribute to the active item.

```
this.active = item.eq(0)
    .children("a")
    .addClass("ui-state-hover")
    .attr("id", "ui-active-menuitem")
    .end();
```

For some reason, IE8 crashes here, although for me **sometimes** does not crash when I remove the `.addClass` and `.attr` lines.

**Edit 2:** OK, for some reason IE is crashing with your `.ui-autocomplete` style. If you change `overflow:scroll;` to `overflow:auto;` then IE8 does not crash. Alternatively change `max-height` to just `height`, which also fixes it. Guess it's a bug in IE either with `max-height` (maybe [IE8 overflow:auto with max-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height)) or `overflow`.

Answer (score 0):

From the first glance this line look strange to me:

```
   if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
       return {
```

But its working fine for me in ie8, in ie7 its not working at all. 
Try if(){return{...}}.

Comment: When made this change as you suggested - script fails (all competed values are undefined)

Answer (score 0):

quick look finds your script tag is missing required type attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I reproduced the issue, copied the file local with no CSS and no fails.

Odd, IF on the original page, I disable CSS using the IE developer tools, it does not crash.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. This doesn't fix the issue sadly.

Comment: If you ran a quick test to use jQuery version 1.6.4 does it still fail? (the page has 1.4.3 on it at the moment)

Comment: Yes it does. It had 1.6.4 in the first place. It is very odd as I'm using original code from jQuery UI examples.

Comment: Confirmed the 1.6.4, and the fail on my browser.  REAL odd that IF I pull this local to my machine, it does not fail - I do not have the source of your CSS file and the images referenced there.  Is it possible to in-line that and remove the image references? (to try to replicate from my local machine.)

Comment: copy of all of the files here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/AutoCompleteIE.zip