# max-height is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue with the max-height applied to a div in bootstrap modal dialog.

Here is the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/z4b2bwg6/5/

**CSS:**

```
.multiline-validation{max-height:100px;overflow-y:auto;}
```

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Launch the fiddler in IE 9 and select a record in grid.
2. Modal dialog will appear.
3. Click on Continue button.
4. Bootstrap alert message will appear with the max height enabled (you will see a scrollbar).
5. Click on the backdrop and then focus on the alert messages.
6. The alert message div (which has max-height enabled) will expand and shrink automatically.

**Question:**

I am wondering what is wrong with my code and why the max height is not working. I am seeing the issue in IE 9.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Related issue in IE8, you could try the hacky workaround and see how it goes?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height

Comment: @GrumbleSnatch, thanks for the link. Tried the suggestion in the link you provided but still, no success.

Comment: Hi Vimalan Jaya Ganesh, When I looked at this in your fiddle it showed the modal was expanded and no scroll. I hit Run and had a view as you said with the scroll. Then had a look at this in IE and used IE9 and IE8 and doing what you said could not see any change. It was odd that when I first viewed it in Chrome and had the two different views. And that was without clicking the back drop. Sorry can't seem to get it to do what you see.

Comment: **Vimalan**, I just noticed that your css code is missing a **semicolon** after `overflow-y:auto` See if it is just this that is causing the issue you see in IE9.

Comment: @AngularJR, thanks for catching the missing semicolon. Even after adding that, I am seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you page runs in standards mode.. (make sure there is a valid doctype).

```
<!doctype html>
```

Also, if IE is in compatibility mode, that can cause problems. Try added the following to you :

```
<!-- Forces user OUT of IE's compatibility mode and removes "broken page" icon --> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```