# overflow: auto and max-height issue in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, scrollbar, overflow

I am facing issue for the below scenario:

When i set max-height and overflow for IE8 the horizontal scroll bar takes the height of max-height even though the content is not more than the max height.

Eg: If you test the below link in chrome you can see that it works fine
[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/paxavecega/edit?html,css,output)

If you test the same code in ie8 it wont work, for IE8 jsbin wont work so you will need to have it in .html file

**CSS**

```
.container {
  overflow:auto;
  max-width:200px;
  max-height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.content {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if this could be a duplicate since there were so many posts on ie8 issue with overflow but i couldnt find any that matched my scenario.

In chrome:
[image]

In IE8:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a image of rigth and wrong visualization of this code?

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for reminding me, i wanted to but forgot

Comment: This seems to be the same issue answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height). Apparently it's an IE8 bug that's never going to be fixed, so the best bet is probably this: ```.container {
      overflow: auto;
     max-width:200px;
     max-height:200px;
     max-height: none\9;
     border:1px solid red;
    }```

Comment: the scenario is not the same, there it is about acting as if overflow:hidden,

Comment: update: trying what jameson mentioned did not solve the issue